# How to find out which application have a problem

Tags: system

It'a a couple of days that each time I boot up Ubuntu (18.04) I get an alert window that claims that a system program have had a problem and the only two options given to me is to send a notification or close the alert.

[image]

Since there's no clue to which application have had the problem and I am a so not-expert of Linux at all, I would like to know if there's a way to find out which application is in order to try to solve the problem in some way.

Thanks everybody

**Edit**

So, I tryed to see in `/var/crash/` but there's only two elements there and both of them are from three days ago, so nothing to do with the daily problem I suppose. So I tryed the journal option as suggested but the result doesn't mean anything to me due to my incomparable ignorance. I post here part of it, the bit I think is relevant due to the timecode, hoping someone can understand it and explain it to me.

```
mar 14 08:55:03 ezabba-Aspire kernel: tpm_crb MSFT0101:00: can't request region for resour
mar 14 08:55:03 ezabba-Aspire kernel: Problem loading UEFI:db X.509 certificate (-65)
mar 14 08:55:03 ezabba-Aspire kernel: Problem loading UEFI:db X.509 certificate (-65)
mar 14 08:55:03 ezabba-Aspire kernel: Couldn't get size: 0x800000000000000e
mar 14 08:55:31 ezabba-Aspire kernel: dell_smbios: Unable to run on non-Dell system
mar 14 08:55:31 ezabba-Aspire kernel: [drm:construct [amdgpu]] *ERROR* construct: Invalid 
mar 14 08:55:31 ezabba-Aspire kernel: [drm:hwss_wait_for_blank_complete [amdgpu]] *ERROR* 
mar 14 08:55:31 ezabba-Aspire kernel: kfd kfd: error getting iommu info. is the iommu enab
mar 14 08:55:31 ezabba-Aspire kernel: kfd kfd: Error initializing iommuv2 for device 1002:
mar 14 08:55:31 ezabba-Aspire kernel: kfd kfd: device 1002:9874 NOT added due to errors
mar 14 08:55:31 ezabba-Aspire kernel: amdgpu: [powerplay] Voltage value looks like a Leaka
mar 14 08:55:31 ezabba-Aspire kernel: amdgpu: [powerplay] Voltage value looks like a Leaka
mar 14 08:55:31 ezabba-Aspire kernel: amdgpu: [powerplay] Voltage value looks like a Leaka
mar 14 08:55:31 ezabba-Aspire kernel: amdgpu: [powerplay] Voltage value looks like a Leaka
mar 14 08:55:31 ezabba-Aspire kernel: amdgpu: [powerplay] Voltage value looks like a Leaka
mar 14 08:55:31 ezabba-Aspire kernel: amdgpu: [powerplay] Voltage value looks like a Leaka
mar 14 08:55:31 ezabba-Aspire kernel: amdgpu: [powerplay] Voltage value looks like a Leaka
mar 14 08:55:31 ezabba-Aspire kernel: [drm:dc_create [amdgpu]] *ERROR* DC: Number of conne
mar 14 08:55:29 ezabba-Aspire systemd-backlight[815]: Failed to get backlight or LED devic
mar 14 08:55:29 ezabba-Aspire systemd-backlight[817]: Failed to get backlight or LED devic
mar 14 08:55:29 ezabba-Aspire systemd[1]: Failed to start Load/Save Screen Backlight Brigh
mar 14 08:55:29 ezabba-Aspire systemd[1]: Failed to start Load/Save Screen Backlight Brigh
mar 14 08:55:40 ezabba-Aspire bluetoothd[993]: Loading LTKs timed out for hci0
mar 14 08:55:48 ezabba-Aspire wpa_supplicant[1027]: dbus: wpa_dbus_get_object_properties: 
mar 14 08:55:48 ezabba-Aspire wpa_supplicant[1027]: dbus: Failed to construct signal
mar 14 08:56:15 ezabba-Aspire spice-vdagent[1517]: Cannot access vdagent virtio channel /d
mar 14 08:57:19 ezabba-Aspire pulseaudio[1918]: [pulseaudio] backend-ofono.c: Failed to re
mar 14 08:57:25 ezabba-Aspire spice-vdagent[2035]: Cannot access vdagent virtio channel /d
lines 1-29...skipping...
-- Logs begin at Sat 2018-11-10 14:10:14 CET, end at Thu 2019-03-14 23:39:02 CET. --
mar 14 08:55:03 ezabba-Aspire kernel: tpm_crb MSFT0101:00: can't request region for resource [mem 0xbfbba000-0xbfbbdfff]
mar 14 08:55:03 ezabba-Aspire kernel: Problem loading UEFI:db X.509 certificate (-65)
mar 14 08:55:03 ezabba-Aspire kernel: Problem loading UEFI:db X.509 certificate (-65)
mar 14 08:55:03 ezabba-Aspire kernel: Couldn't get size: 0x800000000000000e
mar 14 08:55:31 ezabba-Aspire kernel: dell_smbios: Unable to run on non-Dell system
mar 14 08:55:31 ezabba-Aspire kernel: [drm:construct [amdgpu]] *ERROR* construct: Invalid Connector ObjectID from Adapter Service for connector index:2!
mar 14 08:55:31 ezabba-Aspire kernel: [drm:hwss_wait_for_blank_complete [amdgpu]] *ERROR* DC: failed to blank crtc!
mar 14 08:55:31 ezabba-Aspire kernel: kfd kfd: error getting iommu info. is the iommu enabled?
mar 14 08:55:31 ezabba-Aspire kernel: kfd kfd: Error initializing iommuv2 for device 1002:9874
mar 14 08:55:31 ezabba-Aspire kernel: kfd kfd: device 1002:9874 NOT added due to errors
mar 14 08:55:31 ezabba-Aspire kernel: amdgpu: [powerplay] Voltage value looks like a Leakage ID but it's not patched 
mar 14 08:55:31 ezabba-Aspire kernel: amdgpu: [powerplay] Voltage value looks like a Leakage ID but it's not patched 
mar 14 08:55:31 ezabba-Aspire kernel: amdgpu: [powerplay] Voltage value looks like a Leakage ID but it's not patched 
mar 14 08:55:31 ezabba-Aspire kernel: amdgpu: [powerplay] Voltage value looks like a Leakage ID but it's not patched 
mar 14 08:55:31 ezabba-Aspire kernel: amdgpu: [powerplay] Voltage value looks like a Leakage ID but it's not patched 
mar 14 08:55:31 ezabba-Aspire kernel: amdgpu: [powerplay] Voltage value looks like a Leakage ID but it's not patched 
mar 14 08:55:31 ezabba-Aspire kernel: amdgpu: [powerplay] Voltage value looks like a Leakage ID but it's not patched 
mar 14 08:55:31 ezabba-Aspire kernel: [drm:dc_create [amdgpu]] *ERROR* DC: Number of connectors is zero!
mar 14 08:55:29 ezabba-Aspire systemd-backlight[815]: Failed to get backlight or LED device 'backlight:acpi_video1': No such device
mar 14 08:55:29 ezabba-Aspire systemd-backlight[817]: Failed to get backlight or LED device 'backlight:acpi_video0': No such device
mar 14 08:55:29 ezabba-Aspire systemd[1]: Failed to start Load/Save Screen Backlight Brightness of backlight:acpi_video1.
mar 14 08:55:29 ezabba-Aspire systemd[1]: Failed to start Load/Save Screen Backlight Brightness of backlight:acpi_video0.
mar 14 08:55:40 ezabba-Aspire bluetoothd[993]: Loading LTKs timed out for hci0
mar 14 08:55:48 ezabba-Aspire wpa_supplicant[1027]: dbus: wpa_dbus_get_object_properties: failed to get object properties: (none) none
mar 14 08:55:48 ezabba-Aspire wpa_supplicant[1027]: dbus: Failed to construct signal
mar 14 08:56:15 ezabba-Aspire spice-vdagent[1517]: Cannot access vdagent virtio channel /dev/virtio-ports/com.redhat.spice.0
mar 14 08:57:19 ezabba-Aspire pulseaudio[1918]: [pulseaudio] backend-ofono.c: Failed to register as a handsfree audio agent with ofono: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.o
mar 14 08:57:25 ezabba-Aspire spice-vdagent[2035]: Cannot access vdagent virtio channel /dev/virtio-ports/com.redhat.spice.0
mar 14 08:57:46 ezabba-Aspire gnome-session-binary[1390]: Unrecoverable failure in required component org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Color.desktop
mar 14 08:57:46 ezabba-Aspire gnome-session-binary[1390]: CRITICAL: We failed, but the fail whale is dead. Sorry....
```

Comment: inspect the journal for the current boot `jouralctl -p 3 -b`

Comment: fyi: j-money mistyped `journalctl` (it's journal & ctl short for control).  You could also look in /var/crash/ for crash reports  (& see what get's report); the file name provides a pretty good clue as to which program crashed

Comment: I tryed the `journalctl` but sadly the report is far from something I can understand. I edited the question with the journal result

Answer (score 0):

The ubuntu crash reports are stored in /var/crash.

You could do "ls -l /var/crash/" to get a list of the error reports.

Note down the most recent and see if you can address whatever problem that application is having.

Comment: I tryed the `ls -l /var/crash/` but there's only two files there from three days ago, so I think nothing to do with my problem